# Linux finding files -mtime

Tags: linux

So my question is about using find -mtime (and atime & ctime as well). As I already know -mtime -n searches files that are newer than n days, +n older than n days and -mtime n searches files exactly n days old. What if I want to find files that are newer than n days and exactly n days old? Will `find / -type f -mtime -n -mtime n` work? Or I just need to use `find / -type f -mtime -n`? Or both as separate commands?

Comment: Just add `1` to `n` and use `-mtime -n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to add `1` to `$n` when using it with `-mtime`:

```
find / -type f -mtime -$((n+1))
```

But you could use `-o` to combine conditions with `OR` (the default combination is `AND`):

```
find / -type f \( -mtime $n -o -mtime -$n \)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` operators `-o` or `-or` to specify that you want either of your tests to succeed.

Your command should look like this:

```
find / -type f \( -mtime -n -o -mtime n \)
```

Comment: You need parentheses to group properly.

Comment: Without grouping `-mtime n` will list the non `f` types that qualify.

Comment: Oh my, of course you are right. My test cases (and my logic) where faulty. Updated!